# Why does Maven eclipse plugin cause: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'resources'

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, m2eclipse

There are many questions with this title.  After reading them all and confirming I'm have my stuff correct, I have discovered another way to produce this error with Spring's MVC Project (Hello World) template.

I haven't seen anybody discuss this particular avenue.  So, this is why I'm adding another entry to this topic.  I think there's a conflict between Maven and M2E in regards to the .classpath file.  I don't know why it is failing, so I'm demonstrating and asking.

I am using Maven to build my project, and once I use Maven to build the .classpath files (mvn eclipse:eclipse), the error arrives.  If I delete all the .classpath entries from the .classpath file and perform a *Update Maven Project* from the IDE, it works again.

This is how I proved it out.

Create two Spring MVC Projects exactly the same but with two different names.  I named these two projects Matt and Marge respectively.

After adding to the server, both will display Hello World, as expected.

Now, go to a DOS window and execute mvn eclipse:eclipse against Marge (or Matt if you prefer), and redeploy the webapp on the localhost server, and you get the error mentioned in the title.

So, is there something to do with how Maven writes out the .classpath files versus the IDE?  I know Maven and M2E format differently, but am puzzled over this message which I have spent copious amounts of time isolating.

My STS creates the Spring version 3.1.1 if you think that is important.  I can even change Matt (or Marge) to use version 4.1.6 and all is Ok *Until* I execute the Maven classpath writer:  *mvn eclipse:eclipse*  After that, I get this error matching wildcards which seems spurious.

Thank you in advance for any comments.